# Fuel tank pressure - leaking gases and gasoline

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-pump, vacuum, fuel-leak, vacuum-leak

*Hi! A pleasure coming to this site, hope I knew about it before!*

I own a VW Golf 4 R32 (euro), which from time to time, starts leaking gases and fuel from the fuel tank's cap. The amount of fuel leaking isn't *too much*, but the gases create an annoying atmosphere inside the car. I can also hear the noise of the tank's walls contracting/expanding.

I believe the problem may come from the [vacuum valve](https://www.stevensvwspares.com/assets/images/parts/full/IMG_4934_(900x600).jpg) or the fuel pump, but I can't really tell. I already changed the fuel cap, but no differences whatsoever.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

---

*edit*:

*I can't say it's the problem's source, but after looking at my valve's serial number and checking it with the local VW retailer, looks like my car has an incorrect one installed. Will change it and tell the result, soon I hope!*

Comment: You may replace the vecume valve

Comment: Tank caps have been required not to leak for many years ( they do permit air to enter to replace consumed fuel).